# executequery is undefined

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

My Eclipse is Displaying the below Error when I try to add executeQuery in code 
[image]

The stmt is only showing execute and not showing executequery and other execute method

Comment: Which kind of Statement have you imported?

Comment: I dont understand what u r asking

Comment: Can you show your `imports` in this program??

Comment: import for Statement should be java.sql.Statement.

Comment: Wow Thank you  I am new to java How did you learn things like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`java.sql.Statement` is an interface in java.sql package and `java.beans.Statement` is a class in `java.beans` package. you need **[java.sql.Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)** not **[java.beans.Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Statement.html)**.
import `java.sql.Statement`, which has `extecute(str)` and other `overloaded execute methods`. `java.beans.Statement` has only one execute method

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into imports if there is line:

```
import java.sql.Statement;
```

BTW: good practice is to use PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your imports? Make sure you are using the java.sql.Statement